# Eclipse plugin - Class object

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin, and I need Class object of selected file, not IType. Is it possible, and how is the best way to do it?

Edit: when I think about it, the best way is to add it like run as (like junit, profiler, or other plugins are doing). I suppose they must have access to Class (if X is class in question), because they are running it's functions. So how to create plugin that has "run as " action, and get live object?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you want the class represented by the current source file ? Or a representation of that class?

Comment: I have a function doSomething(Class<?> clazz), which my plugin should call, with Class<?> of current source file

Answer (score 2):

In an eclipse plugin, you will, for instance, get the selected file through an [**IAction**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/action/IAction.java.htm).
(it represents the non-UI side of a command which can be triggered by the end user. Actions are typically associated with buttons, menu items, and items in tool bars.)

From there:

```
IResource selectedResource = ResourceUtils.getSelectedResource();
```

[**IResource**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.java.htm) The workspace analog of file system files and directories. There are exactly four *types* of resource: files, folders, projects and the workspace root.

From its type, you can cast it into an **[IFile](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/IFile.java.htm)**, which gives you acces to its full path (`getFullPath()`)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse uses an abstract representation of the object being selected, be it a file (IResource) or be it a Java Type (IJavaType). As it is not required for a source file to be compiled (e.g. disabling auto build), there does not necessarily be a .class file or a Class object for the code being edited. Hence, there is no correct way to get a "Class" object from the a selection in the user interface.

However, as yesterday mentions, you could rely on the fact that the Eclipse builder mechanism will always compile the source files immediately and thus a .class file exists. To reach to this .class file at runtime, you would need to create a dynamic class loader for the project or start a runtime VM. I tried that and it does work, but it is a very unstable approach and can lead to various hard to trace failures.

Comment: So for example JUNIT isn't using any elegant way, but instead some complicated approach? (as they certainly must have compiled sources and loaded also)

Comment: JUnit is starting a new VM and that VM has the compiled classes on its classpath. I'm not sure how JUnitMax is doing the realtime testing, whether they use dynamic class loading or keep a VM in some sort of pool.

Answer (score 0):

The classname of an IType "curIType" can be retrieved through

```
curIType.getFullyQualifiedName()
```

That's the simple part. But then you have the problem, that this class does not have to be in the classloader of your plugin (if it's a class of one of the userprojects, it's seldom part of your classloader). So calling Class.forName(classname) won't do any good.

I had a similar case and did (in a first attempt) solve it by creating an own thread with an own classloader, which included all libraries of the current classloader and all libraries of the type's project. That's neither a short code nor a simple one and I've already refactored it. It's much simpler to get all information out of the IType and not using the classes anywhere in the plugincode.